# CSS Negative margin on both sides

Tags: html, css

How can I have a div with negative margins on both sides so that the div extends off the page on both sides?
I've used negative margins and only the left works, which makes sense.  How can I get the right negative margin to work, as floating right solves the negative right margin but breaks the negative left margin.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: i was just asking to see if there was an established way to do this with just a div

Comment: changing the width also changes the width of the page, i want it to go off both sides of the page

Comment: You could set some overflowing width for div like 120%, then set margin-left to -10% and set in your CSS sheet that user can't see horizontal bar so user couldn't scroll page and see these 10% of div on right side.

Comment: position: fixed solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we dont know how your page look's like, but:

`position: fixed` and set `right` and `left` as negative should do the work.

Comment: should also works with `position: absolute`

Answer (score 2):

You can set the width of the div to more than 100% and then set the negative left margin.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2GJ2q/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="overflow"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#overflow {
   width: 120%;
   height: 300px;
   background: #DCDCDC;
   border: solid 3px #333;
   margin-left: -10px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

In the example you can see that the border around the div only shows on the top and bottom and the sides of the div are hidden outside of the window.

Comment: this expands the page width also, you can scroll and see the edges.  I was looking for a way to have the edges of the div off the sides of the page without changing the page width

Comment: use position then, fixed. :)

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/LBuTj/4/ what @SeanHenderson do is give you the base

Comment: You should be able to add overflow: hidden to prevent scrolling. I'll update the JSFiddle

Comment: @JasonBoggess You can also use `overflow:hidden;` on the parent to achieve the same effect: http://jsfiddle.net/4Vjha/